# My link and route is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My problems started right out of the gates, lol.

Basically, my button linked to a signup form is not going anywhere and just keeps coming back to my home page where I started.

Here is my home page where the sign up button is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flight Scheduler</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>


</nav>
<h1>Welcome to the Flight Scheduler</h1>
<%= button_to "Login", '/login', method: :get%>
<%= button_to "Sign Up", '/users/new', method: :get %>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my route for it.

```
  root 'static#home'

  #users
  get '/users/new', to: 'users#new', as: 'new_user'
```

Lastly here is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @users = User.all
    end
    
    def new
        
        @user = User.new
         
    end
   
    def create
        @user = User.create(user_params)       
                                                                                                                    
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to '/welcome'
    end

 
    

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password,:admin)
end



end
```

When I click the sign-up button it doesn't leave the home page. When modified it earlier, it gives me a error that no route matchs [GET] '/users/new', but when I did my rake routes command it is there. How can I get over this hump?

Comment: Have you restart the server after changed or can I have your repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace the helper `button_to` to `link_to`.

```rb
<%= link_to "Login", '/login' %>
<%= link_to "Sign Up", '/users/new' %>
```

Comment: It was right in front of me this whole time......Its a redirect in my Application controller that is throwing this off. I am sorry for wasting everyone time like this

Answer (score 0):

As said by Vinícius Alonso, you should use link_to instead of button_to. I am guessing that maybe when you click that button you are making an ajax, and RoR is making that request with format .js and with data-remote = true. That means your server are sending a empty body to your front, and instead changing a location are handling that petition by javascript. So, thats why is not changing. With link_to, RoR generates an anchor, and all your troubles will be solved.

If you are using button_to, to making any other behaivor, you just add local= true to button_to helper!

Good luck!

Comment: I mentioned in another comment that a helper method in my application controller has a redirect in it that is throwing this off.